# Can I use SQL Server 2008 management studio with SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have management studio 2005 and 2008, can the 2008 version be setup to connect to 2005? I understand there are new features in 2008 that I wouldn't be able to use, but I mainly use the software to graphical create new tables and assign relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Sql Server Management Studio 2008 works with Sql Server 2005. <s>However, it does **not** work with Sql Server 2000.</s>

I incorrectly stated that it doesn't work with Sql Server 2000, while in fact it does. However, having said that, it's probably not going to give you a whole lot usability options if you're connecting to Sql Server 2000.

Comment: It does work with 2000 as well although, for obvious reasons, some items like DTS are not available. But basic Object Explorer/Query functionality is fine.

Comment: Really? I never got it to work with 2000. Weird. Oh well, I don't use 2000 anymore any ways. :)

Comment: Actually, after getting back to my PC I figured out what wasn't working with SS2000, and that's VS2010. It's the sole reason why I kept my instance of VS2008 installed, and I guess I never bothered to try SSMS 2008 with SS2000...

Comment: How do you make it work with SQL Server 2000? SQL Server 2000 is installed on another machine. It simply does not seem to connect.

Comment: Never mind, on the advanced connection options, I chose named pipes (TCPIP connections to SQL server were blocked on SQL server).